# remove stop words from a text file

Tags: c++

I'm still a beginner to programming, I got an assignment asks me to make a code that read a text file and then remove the stop words. I made a code but it's not that good. what i want is to know how to remove a word from a line and apply case folding to the file after removing the stop words.

here is my code...

```
  string line, deleteline;
 ifstream stopword;
   stopword.open("example.txt");
  if (stopword.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (stopword,line) )
    {
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    stopword.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";

    ofstream temp;
    temp.open("temp.txt");

   cout << "Please input the stop-word you want to delete..\n ";
   cin >> deleteline;

    while (getline(stopword,line))
    {
     if (line != deleteline)
        {
            temp << line << endl;
        }
    }
    temp.close();
    stopword.close();
    remove("example.txt");
    rename("temp.txt","example.txt");
    cout <<endl<<endl<<endl;
system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well done for getting repetitive-I/O right! I was expecting to see `while (!stopword.eof())` (which would have been wrong)

Comment: Do you have one file (example.txt) containing stop words, and the assignment is to remove any of the words appearing in example.txt from temp.txt?  Or is the program only supposed to remove the single stop word that the user enters in `deleteline`?

Comment: (example.txt) is containing a paragraph the assignment is about deleting the stop words from the file(example.txt).

Comment: I tried to enter the stop word manually and then compare it to the lines, but seems not working well. it will delete the whole paragraph.

Comment: All I need to know what should I be aware of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would be right, but you closed the file... and after closing, you're trying to read from it later. That won't quite work, unless you open it again.

Here you close the file (7th line in main):

```
stopword.close();
```

And then, in the 2nd `while` you try to `getline` from that stream:

```
while (getline(stopword,line))
```

In order for that to work, you have to `open` the file again. And `clear` the stream, because it'll probably have the `eofbit` error state flag set.

Comment: really appreciate your comment, I guess the eofbit error was the reason behind deleting the whole file thnx Pawel.....